# Notice: Undefined index: name in upload.php on line making a post from postman

Tags: php, postman

I am trying to make a post from postman to the server. Everything seems alright but when I attempt to make a post it returns an error as shown

```
<th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5">
                <span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in Upload-Download-PDF-File-Demo\upload.php on line
                <i>27</i>
            </th>
```

Here is the snippet on the php file

```
$response = array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request


        //connecting to the database
        //$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request
        $name = $_POST['name'];
```

[Here is a picture on my attempt from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfq9I.png)

This is my first time experiencing this type of error. Please what could be wrong

Comment: this is what is in line 27 $name = $_POST['name']; and nothing else

Comment: @icecub  please see the attached image

Comment: Read the answers already given to you. You need to switch to `x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman. Aside from that, I have no idea. I know nothing about Postman. The error basicly means that `$_POST['name']` doesn't exist. It has no value.

Comment: maybe the title of my question is duplicate but the error I am experiencing at the moment is not duplicate

Comment: @icecub then how do I attach file

Comment: The attached image shows a successful JSON response from the server, not the error you're referring to. Are you showing the correct image?

Comment: please check to see the error image once again

Answer (score 0):

Switch to x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman to mimic an HTML form

Comment: still thesame error because I am unable to attach file

Answer (score -1):

It means you don't have a POSTed value called "name". Probably due to the wrong form encoding.

Comment: see the attached image now